# Output data of NDVI of multiple regions into table from GEE

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, ndvi, multipart, region

I am using GEE for NDVI calculating. There are 150 more counties in USA. I am now stuck in outputting the NDVI ("interest" at code) of each counties listing with "OBJECTID" at the end of code. Could you please help to find the solution?

Here is the code I used.

```
function getNDVI_l8(image){
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI');

}

var images_L8= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterDate('2020-06-01', '2020-07-30')
    // .filterBounds(counties)
    .map(maskL8sr)
    .map(getNDVI_l8)
    .median().clip(counties);

Map.addLayer(images_L8,{color:'900000'});
// var interest1 = [];
for (var countyID =1; countyID < 156; countyID++){

  var shp =counties.filterMetadata('OBJECTID', 'equals', countyID);
  
  Map.addLayer(shp,{color:'900000'});
  var interest = images_L8.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: shp,
    scale: 30
  });
  // interest1 = interest.append(interest);
  print(interest);    
  
}

Export.table.toDrive({
      collection:interest,
      description:'USA_county_NDVI',
        folder:'USA_NDVI',
        fileFormat:'csv'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run your code as you have it now, `interest` isn't filled in at all - it's set to null for every value. This is because you're mixing server- and client-side objects, which [you can't do in earth engine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/best_practices#avoid-mixing-client-functions-and-objects-with-server-functions-and-objects). `countyID` is a client-side variable (since you initialize it using var), while the value assigned to `OBJECTID` is server-side. Even if their values are the same, `filterMetadata` will never find them to be equal because they're different types of objects.

This type of problem is one reason (but not the only one) that for-loops are generally discouraged in earth engine. Instead, you should map over `counties` as a FeatureCollection:

```
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2018/Counties");

counties = counties.map(function(shp){  
  var interest = images_L8.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: shp.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  return shp.set('ndvi', interest);
}
```

That will create a new property for each element of `counties` and set it equal to the mean NDVI.